# Como consumir un servicio web en jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio

Tengo un cliente en C# que consume un servicio web pasando varios parametros.

Lo que estoy buscando hacer es traducir esta llamada que esta hecha en C# y hacerla en jQuery.

He buscado en varios foros pero la información no esta completa.

Podrian indicarme como poder traducir el siguiente codigo y el explicarme una vez este hecho el codigo en jQuery como se ejecuta?

Muchas gracias

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
dynamic myURL;
dynamic myKey;
dynamic myBlockURL;
dynamic myUser;


//TODO: Change the following based on your BPI information.
myURL = "http://localhost/test/webservice.asmx/test";
myKey = "BIA38KRVQ6V2MQnvmUnC";
myBlockURL = "http://localhost/test/test.aspx?blockid=_zu&culture=&userid=";

//TODO: Change the following to the username of the person logged in
myUser = "User1";

// Create a server object to use to encrypt the user ID
dynamic objHTTP;
objHTTP = Interaction.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
objHTTP.open("POST", myURL);
objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


 /*Construct a URL with a query string to encrupt the user ID*/
 dynamic strPost;
 strPost = "sourcetxt=" + myUser + "&Key=" + myKey;

 // Construct a URL with a query string to encrupt the user ID
 strPost = null;
 strPost = "sourcetxt=" + myUser + "&Key=" + myKey;

 // Perform the query
 objHTTP.Send(strPost);

 // Retrieve the encrypted user ID from the result of the query
 dynamic encryptedID = null;
 if (objHTTP.statusText != "Unauthorized" & objHTTP.statusText != "Not Found")
 {
     dynamic oXMLDoc = null;
     oXMLDoc = Interaction.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
     oXMLDoc.loadXML(objHTTP.ResponseText);
     encryptedID = oXMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("string")(0).childNodes(0).text;
     objHTTP = null;
 }

 // Output some HTML with an iFrame, the BPI block URL and the encrypted user ID
 Response.Write(" <iframe src='" + myBlockURL + encryptedID + "' id='Test' scrolling='yes' width='900' height='400'></iframe>");
}
```

Aqui esta el codigo que hago tratando de imitar en ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=btnSubmit]").click(function () {
            var myURL = $.trim($("[id*=myURL]").val());
            var myKey = $.trim($("[id*=myKey]").val());
            var myBlockURL = $.trim($("[id*=myBlockURL]").val());
            var myUser = $.trim($("[id*=myUser]").val());

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/test/webservice.asmx/test",
                data: "{ myURL: '" + myURL + "', myKey: " + myKey + ",myBlockURL:" + myBlockURL + ",myUser:" + myUser + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r.d);
                },
                error: function (r) {
                    alert(r.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (r) {
                    alert(r.responseText);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: porque has puesto la etiqueta de asp.net-web-api ? en el codigo veo que estas invocando un servicio web asmx, eso no es web api, para serlo deberias invocar servicios creados en asp.net mvc

Comment: @LeandroTuttini tienes toda la razon, voy a borrar esa etiqueta. Gracias por la remarca

Comment: No es la misma, pero si queria cambio a ASP.NET MVC, aqui es un tip que muestra como se envie data entre jquery/AJAX al client y C# al server: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1095263/Minimalistic-Example-of-Sending-and-Receiving-Data (pero en ingles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando jquery el codigo generado es completamente diferentes al de c#

Usarias `$.ajax`

[Call (Consume) Web Service (ASMX) using jQuery AJAX in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-Consume-Web-Service-ASMX-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Como observaras la idea es usar una estructura como esta

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Service.asmx/GetDetails",
        data: "{ name: '" + name + "', age: " + age + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (r) {
            alert(r.responseText);
        }
    });
```

En tu caso en el parametro `url` de `$.ajax` indicarias el `/webservice.asmx/test`

Puedes indicarle en el `data` la información que enviarias a los parametros del servicio.

Comment: hice como me dijiste, pero cuando creo un formulario para poner todos los parametros que paso en el scritp, este no me devuelve nada. He editado la pregunta para agregar mis cambios pero no logro hacerlo, puedes sugerirme para ver donde me estoy equivocando? muchas gracias